# Text besides a JTextField

Tags: java, text

So I need to develop a login application where you'd have;

Username [JTextField]
Password [JTextField]
My question is; how can I put text adjacent to the JTextField? Would I use a JLabel?

What layout manager should I use? (Baring in mind I've looked at documentation and can't make my mind up).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JLabel have you tried it?

Comment: @Luminous_Dev I find it hard to align.

Comment: A layout manager will help you align the two objects.

Comment: I successfully used [MIGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It's simple and powerful. Don't use JavaFX if you can. It's really heavy and slow. But that's my *personal* opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using JavaFx if it is available. The reason why is because there is something called SceneBuilder that lets you drag and drop different items onto the pane that you are creating.

If you wanted to use swing your best bet would be to use a JLabel, and then the JTextField next to the said JLabel. Honestly, I think javafx is much easier to use, and if you are considering using it I would watch these tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLkOX4Eez6o
Best of luck! :)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed and speedy response, I did look in to JavaFX and if you suggest it then I'll take another look.

Comment: Very well, I found it very easy and self explanatory to use especially with those tutorials I suggested to you. If you liked my  answer you should make it the accepted answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: I have done, your answer was very helpful. Austins FlowLayout idea worked very well too, thank you all for the assistance.   http://prntscr.com/dbdnqu.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going forward with Java Swing, I suggest using `gridbaglayout` as your layout. It was very easy for me to learn when I first started swing, and it's pretty much the only layout I use now.

You would use `JLabels` next to the textfields, also, there is something called a `JPasswordField` that may come into use for you as well.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi there, I will take another look at this layout! I forgot about JPassworldFields until about three minutes ago, but thank you anyway, I appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 0):

You Could setup you code like this however this only works if your frame is a certain size.

```
import java.awt.* ;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Setup extends JFrame
{
    TextField username = new TextField(15);
    JLabel uLabel= new JLabel("Username");
    TextField password = new TextField(15);
    JLabel pLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    Setup( String title)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize( 325, 400 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        frame.add(username);
        frame.add(uLabel);
        frame.add(password);
        frame.add(pLabel);

    }
    public static void main (String[] args )
    {
        Setup frame = new Setup("Login");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah of course, so the components would simply be added next to each other - all I would have to figure out is the dimension of the Frame. Thank you for the advice!